# Word contractions in Shakespeare's plays

Tags: pronunciation, contractions, early-modern-english

In Shakespeare's plays it is common to find contracted words, such as "o'er", "e'en", "sulph'uous", "ta'en". Is it just a literary device or those words were actually pronounced (in day-to-day speech) that way in Early Modern English?

Comment: I am speculating, but it seems natural, that they were pronounced exactly like that, even in day-to-day speech, but in the case it was in iambic pentameter. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are generally known as poetic tropes. When writing in iambic pentameter, it is necessary to alternate stressed and unstressed syllables, and measure feet to each line. Many of the contractions you see used by Shakespeare and other writers of the period are being employed to make the words fit a particular rhyming or verse scheme.

Some [examples are given here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter), including this line by Donne:

> That I / may rise / and stand / o'er
>   throw / me and bend

You can see how the contraction makes the fourth foot work properly.

Comment: Correct, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Or the opposite when folk singers have to make it "californ-eye-ah" to fit the rhyme.

Comment: Well, it does, Colin - in the sense that "poetic convention" is signaled and the works in question were written to be spoken aloud. Any speech marked as "poetic" is normally understood to be common to that purpose (but not others).

Comment: No, it doesn't answer the question. Suppose we have a song writer today who writes  the lyrics "we gon' make it right." And suppose somebody asks: do people really ever say "we gon' make ..." or did she write it like that just to make it fit the music? Your reply is "the contraction is being employed to make the wrods fit a particular verse scheme". That doesn't answer the actual question, which is "do people ever say "we gon' make" when they're not writing song lyrics?

Answer (score 3):

It's a literary device known as [syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology)#As_a_poetic_device), the removal of syllables or letters from the middle of a word. It was used to fit the 10 syllables per line of iambic pentameter.

> **[syncope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syncope)**
> **noun**
> 2: the loss of one or more sounds or letters in the interior of a word (as in *fo'c'sle* for *forecastle*).
>
> [source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Shakespeare also removed syllables or letters from the beginning of words (aphaearesis), and sometimes the end (apocope).  I've seen these used as diction in the dialogue of a few novelists.

Comment: Hi Darin, welcome to EL&U! Your answer offers useful new information, and as you're a new contributor I've upvoted it, but normally I wouldn't give it a vote because it's not supported by any evidence to distinguish it from mere opinion or guesswork. For guidance, see [answer] and take our short but useful [Tour]. And to give you an example of what we're looking for, I've edited your post to add some linked references. I look forward to your next contribution. :-)